# H5py import not working in Maya

Tags: python, keras, maya, h5py

I'm trying to install h5py in Maya. It seems like its installed properly in the correct folder, i.e. : `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\Python\Lib\site-packages\h5py`. But when I try to import `h5py` in Maya's Python tab, I'm getting the following error

```
ImportError: file C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\Python\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py line 26: 
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Maya's interpreter is slightly nonstandard, particularly when it comes to binary extensions.  You have to compile binaries with the right version of Visual Studio for your version of Maya.  Do you have the binary extension that goes with that h5.py?

Comment: maya is compiled with a version of python 2.7 and VS2012, you might to have to compile it with the same version as maya. see there http://around-the-corner.typepad.com/adn/2016/08/compiler-versions-for-maya-2017.html

Comment: Thank you for replying . I am following this particular tutorial http://3deeplearner.com/neural-network-inside-maya/                                                           the author has provided a version of h5py for Maya 2018 , not sure if i have the correct binary extension , what would be the best way to check that ?

Comment: add i am using windows 10 , can that be a problem?

Comment: Installation doesn't seems correct; is it copied pasted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this thing working , if anyone is facing this issue please follow the following article http://3deeplearner.com/neural-network-inside-maya/
The author of this tutorial helped a lot with the required solution for this issue 
Thank you Gus from 3deeplearner.com